# Report Filtering With Adobe Analytics API

Tags: adobe-analytics

I am queuing and getting a report through the API and javascript, but now I want to start filtering the report.  I want the results that come back to apply only to the user (other filters are needed too) who is requesting the report.  What is the best way to put a filter on the initial report queue?

The way I am doing it now is adding a selected element to the report description:

...

```
"elements": [
            { "id": "page" },{ "id": "evar23" , "selected": ["295424","306313"]}
```

...

But this only seems to apply to the breakdown section of the results, not the top level count that is returned.  I would expect the top level count in the below example be 66, not 68:

...

```
"counts":[
        "68"
        ],
                "breakdown":[
                    {
                        "name":"306313",
                        "url":"",
                        "counts":[
                            "43"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"295424",
                        "url":"",
                        "counts":[
                            "23"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
```

,...

I know I can just crawl through the breakdown array and total up what I need, but the more filters I apply the messier it becomes.  All of a sudden I am three levels deep in a nested array, making sure that all 3 breakdown names match my conditions.  There must be a better way to do this, any ideas?  Many thanks.

Comment: right. the top level count is just that: top level. It's so you can compare the selected #'s against the overall total. Having the top level count match your selected data is a waste of bandwidth because you *can* just add them up yourself.

Comment: Well in my case it is actually a huge waste of bandwidth to have nested breakdowns depending on how many filters I want to apply.  I can't imagine what this will start to look like when I have multiple selected values for each element, or if I tried to apply a filter with > logic instead of =.                                                                                                            I am only interested in filtering the total results, I do not need any sort of grouped data returned.  Do you know of a way to do this?

Comment: I found a solution below if interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there are some possible limitations to them that I am still working through, it seems that **segments** is what I need, not **elements**.

```
"segments": [
{
    "element": "evar23","selected": ["295424","306313"]
}]
```

https://marketing.adobe.com/developer/forum/reporting/report-filtering-with-api